# How to construct a possibly nonempty Set in Agda

Tags: types, agda

I know that (A \/ ~A) is not provable in general. How does one go about constructing an example of a set A where (A \/ ~A) is not provable, is this possible? And if it is possible, is it possible without quantifiers?

Comment: What do you mean by "without quantifiers"?

Comment: BTW, all `A` propositions that are independent from Agda are such that `A \/ ~A` is unprovable. Classical logical axioms are such, or axiom K (if we use the `--without-K` language option), function extensionality, Gödel sentences of Agda, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that (A / ~A) is not provable in general. How does one go
>   about constructing an example of a set A where (A / ~A) is not
>   provable,

You have already given an example: `A \/ ~A` itself.

```
open import Level
open import Data.Empty
open import Relation.Nullary
open import Data.Sum

lem-for : ∀ {α} -> Set α -> Set α
lem-for A = A ⊎ ¬ A

lem : ∀ {α} -> Set (suc α)
lem = ∀ {A} -> lem-for A

lem-lem : ∀ {α} -> Set (suc α)
lem-lem = lem-for lem
```

`lem` says "for all `A` `A` is either true or false". `lem-lem` says "the law of excluded middle is either true or false". But we know that constructively `lem` is not true and, since Agda is not anti-classical, `lem` is not false either.

Other classical logic axioms (taken from the [Software Foundations](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/sf/current/Logic.html) book) are

```
Definition peirce := ∀P Q: Prop,
  ((P→Q)→P)→P.
Definition classic := ∀P:Prop,
  ~~P → P.
Definition de_morgan_not_and_not := ∀P Q:Prop,
  ~(~P ∧ ¬Q) → P∨Q.
Definition implies_to_or := ∀P Q:Prop,
  (P→Q) → (¬P∨Q).
```

These all + `lem` are equivalent.

---

Here is a fancier example:

```
open import Relation.Binary.PropositionalEquality
open import Data.Bool.Base
open import Data.Fin

eq : Set₁
eq = Fin 2 ≡ Bool
```

---

"Extensional" predicates are of the same sort. The simplest is function extensionality, but we can also say

```
open import Coinduction
open import Data.Nat.Base
open import Data.Stream

zeros : Stream ℕ
zeros = 0 ∷ ♯ zeros

eq₂ : Set
eq₂ = zeros ≡ 0 ∷ ♯ zeros
```

Comment: Can you explain the fin 2 example? I read the code for prop equality but still don't quite get it. If I define two bools bool1 and bool2 in the same manner is bool1===bool2 also unprovable?

Comment: @davik, yep, `bool1 ≡ bool2` is unprovable. You can prove this in [OTT](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~psztxa/publ/obseqnow.pdf) or [HoTT](http://homotopytypetheory.org/), but not in Agda.

Comment: How do we prove something like ⊤ ≢ ⊥? or is this impossible too?

Comment: @davik, inequalities are often provable. See [this](https://github.com/wjzz/Agda-small-developments-and-examples/blob/master/UnitNotBool.agda), [this](https://github.com/effectfully/random-stuff/blob/master/Fin-injective.agda) and [this](https://gist.github.com/AndrasKovacs/bca6a3a88e2d045608d9).